# How to include page break in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

i have created crystal report with static label and dynamic values. Kindly help me how to include page break after ten lines of static labels.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `details` section's force-new-page-after conditional formula:

```
Remainder(RecordNumber, 10) = 0
```

Comment: can you plz give formula syntax for field value.

Comment: I don't understand what you ask asking.